# @r with the [name=] specification

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to know if the @r command works with the [name=] specification, aim trying to make a underwater map with randomized fish using invisible squids and i want to only select the ones named squid (meaning the unnamed ones since a squid's default name is squid)

Comment: I thought an entity had no name unless it had a Name NBT tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, but you have to specify the type of mob it is, or it won't target entities. As per the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors):

> When used without the `type` argument, `@r` always targets a random player. The `type` argument can be used to target non-player entities [...]

Here is a example:

```
/tp @r[type=Squid,name=Random] ~ ~3 ~
```

This would teleport a random Squid with the name "Random" 3 blocks up.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to the Site! Good first answer. I didn't believe @r could target entities, you so I looked it up on the wiki. Turns out you are right, so I took the liberty of adding the relevant section to your answer for all the other doubters. Feel free to roll-back if you don't like it though. (To do so, click on "edited TIME ago" to see the edit history and click "rollback".)